# find the radius of convergence of the following power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n!}$

My textbook says its answer is 1. But I think the sequence is not power series because it cannot be expressed as the form of $CnZ^n$.

Am I right? Or where do I have a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your text book is right.

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}$ is a power series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {c_n z^n}$ with
$$
c_n=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n=k!$ for some integer $k$,}\\
0 & \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: It's awesome! Thank you very much, and I feel that math is beautiful :)